# Как выполнить сортировку рубрик wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Как выполнить сортировку названий рубрик в иерархической последовательности в записи?
Есть такая иерархия рубрик:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но выводит названия в по алфавиту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сохранить эту иерархию при выводе?

Comment: каким образом выводите?

Comment: Приведите код вывода рубрик.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать плагин mycategoryorder.
Сортируете категории как Вам нужно. Для вывода сортировки в аргументы передаете элемент массива orderby со значением order

```
     $args = array(
................
'orderby'                  => 'order',
................ );

 $a_parent = get_categories($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам стоит воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
/* вывод списка рубрик */
$args = array(
   'parent'                   => 0,
   'hide_empty'               => 0,
   'exclude'                  => '21',
   'number'                   => '0',
   'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
   'pad_counts'               => true,
   'orderby' => 'name',
   //Сосртировка
   'order' => 'ASC'
 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Для более сложных вещей используйте the_query и wp_query